# Reset drag and drop filelist every time bootstrap-modal hides or closes

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal, filelist

**Background**

I'm creating a from where the user can upload information and add an image file. The form information and file name is stored in a mysql db. I'm using Bootstrap to do the styling of the site.

On this page I use the bootstrap modal to bring up the form for the user to complete. The form has a drag and drop file upload area. The file is uploaded once the form is submitted.

Once the file is dropped the info about the file is displayed in the modal inside a `<div>` place holder.

**Problem**

The problem is that when a record with a file is submitted the modal containing the form is then closed (hidden) from the user. The form should rest. When the form is then opened again to add another record and a file is added, *the image holder is loaded twice*. The number of times that the image holder is replicated depends on the number of times that the modal was shown before.

**Question**

How do change my script so that the array that olds the file information is reset with every from or `modal('show')`

My script is here https://jsfiddle.net/mielie007/9vz5m7da/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to reset the entire form when the modal is being shown. Your issue is the image uploader right?

Have you tried to reset the input value to blank as follow:

```
$('#file').val("");
```

Let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Best

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that and it doesn't work. If updated my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mielie007/9vz5m7da/3/) script to show your suggestion. I'm thinking that it is the counter in the `$each()` function that needs to be reset before the showfiles function is called, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Somewhere there is a counter that the browser keeps of the number of files that have been added and I haven't worked out how to reset that. I've tried the showfiles function with a `$each()`, a `for()` loop, a `do{ }while()` every time while reseting the counter without any luck